# How to setup Eclipse Neon to run on a Linux system that uses Java 1.7

Tags: eclipse-neon

Redhat Enterprise Linux(RHEL) 6.7
Java version "1.7.0_80"
Eclipse Juno 3.8.2
Eclipse Neon 4.6

In a few months my project will be moving from Eclipse 3 to Eclipse 4.  I would like to get ready by playing around with Eclipse Neon.  My environment variables ( Linux ) are set up with Java 1.7.

Obviously, I can download Java 1.8 as Eclipse Neon requires.

At this point I can't even get Eclipse Neon to boot up because of this dependency.   How can I get Eclipse Neon to point to a downloaded Java 1.8 before it boots up?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the path to a particular JVM you want Eclipse to use by editing the `eclipse.ini` file in the Eclipse install directory and adding the -vm line followed by the path to the Java.

For example:

```
-vm
/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java
```

Note: This must be two lines. It must be **above** any -vmargs entry in the file.

Comment: Another possibilty is to simply remove this 2 lines. Then Eclipse will rely on you JAVA_HOME and/or PATH environment variables to detect the Java Runtime to use. If those are set to Java 8, then Java 8 would be used.

Comment: This advice is also good for Windows 7, but Eclipse Neon then says it requires version 1.8 or greater.

Comment: Should it necessarily point to the java from JDK or from JRE is sufficient?

Comment: @alisa Eclipse only needs the JRE to run